# Rajawali Environment Texture on one (merged) object

Tags: 3d, rajawali

Is there a way to merge geometry?

i have some spheres and i added em to an Object3D (container). Each sphere as somewhat of a glass texture abd i want to have an environment texture for reflections. But i can only add the Envtexture
to the child spheres but then i have the environment look like in small on each sphere (doesn't look correct) So i would like to have the whole object as a reflectin object. But when i add the env texture to the container object i have nothing but the glass texture on each sphere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can merge geometries directly(AFAIK) in `Rajawali`, However, mapping each sphere seperately should work correctly. As environment is sampled based on a direction vector which depends on     vertex position.